# "Unable to acquire application service." when running STS on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, spring-tool-suite

I tried to install STS on Mac, but when I try to run it I get this error:

An error has occurred.
See the log file
/Users/X/Downloads/sts-bundle/STS.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/1436874402230.log.

In log file (full log is available here [log](http://adrian.home.pl/1436874402230.log)) :

```
> !SESSION 2015-07-14 12:46:41.954
> ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=3.7.0.201506290652-RELEASE-e45 java.version=1.6.0_65
> java.vendor=Apple Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64,
> WS=cocoa, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
> org.springsource.sts.ide -keyring /Users/X/.eclipse_keyring
> -showlocation Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide -keyring
> /Users/X/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
> 
> This is a continuation of log file
> /Users/X/Downloads/sts-bundle/STS.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/1436874402230.bak_1.log Created Time: 2015-07-14 12:46:46.045
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer 2 0 2015-07-14 12:46:46.045
> !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer [305] 
> Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs
>     -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103";
> bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.core.jobs"; version="0.0.0"
>        org.eclipse.core.jobs [146]
>          Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
> 
> (...)
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.ui 2 0 2015-07-14 12:46:46.063
> !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.ui
> [543]   Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui;
> bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
>     -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.107.0.v20150507-1945"; singleton:="true"
>        org.eclipse.ui [785]
>          Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
>            -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
>               org.eclipse.core.runtime [149]
>                 Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)";
> visibility:="reexport"
>                   -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
>                      org.eclipse.core.jobs [146]
>                        Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
> 
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-07-14 12:46:46.065 !MESSAGE
> Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
> acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime
> bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).  at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Few details:

- OS X version: Yosemite and 10.9 (I tried on both)
- STS version: 3.7.0
  (the newest available on sts web page)
- Java version:

  java version "1.6.0_32"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.4) (rhel-6.1.13.4.el7_0-x86_64)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))
```

is saying that you must use Java 7 (or 8)

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of STS (3.7.0) require a JDK 1.7 to run. Please install that version from Oracle.